# How to send the fetched data everytime to some other widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-state

Wanted to pass the updated values of `fetchedEntriesInApp` to `PasswdList` widget everytime it loads.

Below is my code.

main.dart

```
Future fetchEntries() async {
  var fetchedEntries = [];
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final res = await db.collection("password_entries").get().then((event) {
    for (var doc in event.docs) {
      var resDic = {
        "entry_id": doc.id,
        "data": doc.data(),
      };
      fetchedEntries.add(resDic);
    }
  });

  return fetchedEntries;
}


class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  late Future fetchedEntriesInApp;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchedEntriesInApp = fetchEntries();
  }

  void refreshEntries() {
    setState(() {
      fetchedEntriesInApp = fetchEntries();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {});
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchedEntriesInApp!,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text('Loading');
          }

          return Column(children: [
            PasswdList(fetchedEntriesInApp),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  '/addPasswd',
                  arguments: AddPasswd(fetchEntries),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Add Psswd'),
            ),
          ]);
        });
  }
}
```

PasswdList Widget

```
class PasswdList extends StatefulWidget {
  var abc;
  PasswdList(this.abc);
  @override
  State<PasswdList> createState() => _PasswdListState();
}

class _PasswdListState extends State<PasswdList> {
  var fetchedEntriesInApp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var entries;
    setState(() {
      entries = widget.abc;
    });
    print(entries);
    return Container(
      height: 500,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          PasswdCard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one variable for password list in your password list widget like,

```
class PasswdList extends StatefulWidget {
   
   var passwordlist;
  PasswdList(this.passwordlist);
  @override
  State<PasswdList> createState() => _PasswdListState();
}




class _PasswdListState extends State<PasswdList> {
  var fetchedEntriesInApp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var entries;
    setState(() {
      entries = widget.passwordlist;
    });
    print(entries);
    return Container(
      height: 500,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          PasswdCard(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you can pass it to the navigator like,

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) =>PasswdList (fetchedEntriesInApp.values,
    ),
 );
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your **PasswdList** is a **Stateful widget** and it is embedded in your view, you can use the callback

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(covariant PasswdList oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (widget.abc != oldWidget.abc)
        setState(() {
            //You can have a var in your state class and re-assign it to the new value
        });
}
```

**Note:** in order for this to work, you need to re-initialize the **abc** list and pass it to your widget, otherwise you might need to change the if statement condition